# Deletion from Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-delete

I have a huge amount of data in a table, I am deleting data from table with below query. But it is taking about 2-3 hours to delete about 3-4 million rows. Is there any fast method to delete.

```
DELETE /*+parallel (aa 64)*/
from ua_contacthistory_bkp PARTITION (ua_contacthistory_bkp_08JUL2018) aa
WHERE aa.CAMPAIGN_CODE='C000000333'
```

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious - dropping the whole partition -  are you deleting everything in that partition, or are there other campaign codes in there that you wan to keep?

Comment: @AlexPoole there are other campaign codes as well.I want to delete some specific campaign data

Answer (score 2):

Note that to perform parallel DML you must [enable](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-5EB01FA8-030B-45BB-9B16-2D13881F6010.htm) it using

```
 ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
```

or the hint `ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML`.

According to the used degree of parallelism a good way is to test with say 4, 8, 16 etc. to see if the increase of `DOP` realy scales, i.e. effectively reduces the `elapsed time`.

You may find that `DOP`of 64 is not the best option e.g. if you encounter a disc system bottleneck.

Technically you may also implement a [composite partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-BE424ACC-F746-4CA8-973C-F578CF98FF10.htm#VLDBG00225) using a LIST subpartitioning schema based on `CAMPAIGN_CODE` under your current partitioning.

This could either completely avoid the `delete` in favor of using `DROP SUBPARTITION` or at least further limit the scope of the `DELETE`statement.

**Offline Reorganisation**

If you can put the partition for a short time offline (i.e. there are no other sessions modifying it) this simple and effective approach will remove the records without a delete.

1) create a temporary table based on your original partition exluding the data you don't want to preserve.

```
CREATE TABLE TMP as
SELECT * FROM  ua_contacthistory_bkp PARTITION (ua_contacthistory_bkp_08JUL2018) aa
WHERE nvl(aa.CAMPAIGN_CODE,'x') != 'C000000333'
```

The `WHERE` predicate selects all data (inclusive NULLs) except of the rows with the code to be deleted.

2) Exchange the new temp table with your partition

```
alter table ua_contacthistory_bkp exchange partition ua_contacthistory_bkp_08JUL2018
with table TMP
including indexes;
```

Now the `TMP` table contains the complete data (you may drop it or whatever you like) and the partition `ua_contacthistory_bkp_08JUL2018` all the original data except for the deleted code.

You need to take some care if the partitioned table is indexed. Local index can be created on the TMP table and exchange as well (see `including indexes`) global indexes must be rebuild.

This approach has positive side effects as you can compress the table or reorder the data (using `ORDER BY` in the creation of `TMP`) to optimize the access.

Answer (score 1):

I can't know your tables conditions and business logic,

> but I'd rather prefer adding an integer type, not null column with a
>   default value of `1`, named as `active` to my table, and prefer
>   `updating` it instead of `deleting`( *to **show** or **hide** all of the row data, have an opportunity to take a glance at the deleted records easily whenever desired* ), especially for tables which has
>   millions of rows and lots of columns .

`Deleting` is known as an expensive operation compared to `Updating` and `Inserting`, especially from the point of *Undo Data Production Action*. For `Inserting` you need only  `ROWID` column to be inserted into the `Undo` segment, but as you `Deleting` you're `Inserting` all columns to the `Undo` segment even if you have one-hundred columns in your table. i.e. they're reverse operations. By the way, if `Updating` just a column(`active`) is preferred, then Undo segment shall be concerned with `ROWID` and `active` columns, that's all.